# How can I populate a file with random data?

Tags: random

How can I create a new file and fill it with 1 Gigabyte worth of random data? I need this to test some software.

I would prefer to use `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

On most unices:

```
head -c 1G </dev/urandom >myfile
```

If your `head` doesn't understand the `G` suffix you can specify the size in bytes:

```
head -c 1073741824 </dev/urandom >myfile
```

If your `head` doesn't understand the `-c` option (it's common but not POSIX; you probably have OpenBSD):

```
dd bs=1024 count=1048576 </dev/urandom >myfile
```

[Do not use `/dev/random` on Linux, use `/dev/urandom`.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939)

Comment: Interesting that `head` can read `/dev/urandom`, but `tail` cannot.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski `tail` first tries to go to the end of the input file, which takes forever (literally).

Comment: Ah, like 'tail /dev/infinity`, if there was such a device.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski You have `/dev/zero` as well, if you don't like variety.

Comment: If `head` don’t understand G, `$((1<<30))` in [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) is easier to remember.

Comment: Correction to my last comment: [Arithmetic Expansion is POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) so it doesn’t have to be Bash.

Comment: No need for that first `<` file redirect, this works:  `head -c 1G /dev/urandom >myfile`

Comment: @agc, no need to pass `/dev/urandom`  to `head` for it to open it as the shell can open it by itself with `< /dev/urandom`, saving that extra effort.

Answer (score 55):

Assuming that pseudo-random data is sufficient, `dd if=/dev/urandom of=target-file bs=1M count=1000` will do what you want.

[dd(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) will read blocks of data from an input file and write them to an output file.  The command line language is a little quirky, but it is one of those really useful tools worth mastering the basics of.

In this case `if` is input file, `of` is output file, `bs` is "block size" - and I used the GNU extension to set the size more conveniently. (You can also use 1048576 if your `dd` doesn't have GNU extension.)  `count` is the number of blocks to read from `if` and write to `of`.

`/dev/urandom` is a better choice than `/dev/random` becuase, on Linux, it will fall back to strong pseudo-random data rather than blocking when genuinely random data is exhausted.

You may also want to look at http://www.random.org/ as another path to getting some random data without having to generate it yourself.

Comment: A note -- unit specifications like `1M` are not available in every standard `dd` variant. If your version of `dd` is affected, use `bs=1048576`.

Comment: The example command will create a file of count 1,000,000 blocks each of size 1 MB. That's about 1 TB (1M x 1MB), not 1 GB (which would be 1K x 1MB). As an aside, up to a point, increasing block size and reducing the block count tends to yield better throughput for a given amount of output data.

Comment: GB vs GiB. for dd `1M==1024*1024`, use 1MB and `count=1000` if you want 1 GB or 1M and `count=1024` if you want 1 GiB. Or use 1GB or 1G and `count=1`.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to using `/dev/random/` and/or `/dev/urandom` with an excellent [Cryptographically **Secure** PseudoRandom Number Generator (CSPRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)  is given by openssl. You can even choose the algorithm and encrypting method in such rare cases that that is needed:

```
size=$( echo 1G | numfmt --from=iec )         # 1 G ==> 1073741824

openssl rand -out myfile "$size"
```

If you need base64:

```
openssl rand -base64 -out myfile "$size"
```

Read `man rand` for the details.

Answer (score 6):

```
while true;do head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9;done | head -c 5000K | tee  5000kb
```

Used this to generate 5MB random character data. If you need different size, change the `-c` value of head, change the outfile name, execute and wait until the execution completes.

Comment: Use `base64` to increase recall rate (from 62 / 256 to 62 / 64).

Answer (score 2):

The solution doesn't use random but I use man pages to create sizable data. This does not however guarantee the max size so we might have to loop through a few `cat`s to get the desired size,

```
man curl > /tmp/man-curl
```

Or if the size required is larger,

```
for i in {1..10}; do man curl >> /tmp/man-curl; done
```

Answer (score 2):

The UNIX tool `jot` can do exactly that. No need to pipe data from `/dev/urandom` into a file with `dd`.

```
jot -r -c $FILESIZE > $FILE
```

The flag `-r` generates random data based on `arc4random(3)`, `-c` generates a char based on the ASCII table. Other data can be specified based on `printf` format types with the `-w` flag.

By default `jot` returns to stdout.

---

Edit:

Another use case of `jot` could be to generate random passwords:

```bsh
$ jot -rcs '\'\'' 128 33 126
wFv/Fb7F}iO'|!cGy>?8yyez2$f,vy5vYqa;?s$-wBlVU^QX0|y~M.VeRq7}Jh!l/0'CcveuLTL]_1@P_yV#P)h8VZA\~,s{|69P{YwlL?;U{_yC3$\m*:H2V66RpdJ^
$ jot -rcs '\'\'' 128 33 126
X`&kh3[Z2'ej)w`7z'YXl~VG_MA@^jk6+STuB@.C/i\u)&g1|Y}%8;r>o>e5$UcyX]Q(F=XH6C@-BOTQ!<}CqI1Ff],7#;kb!GpZ^Ai85NaA,ya|YF+EuH]{FUgC0G7;
```

Comment: This one? https://lib.rs/crates/jot.  Since it was not available in my system's software repository (Fedora).  So `cargo install jot`?