# Writing /dev/random to file?

Tags: kernel, devices, random

If you ran the following, what would happen?

```
# Do not run.
# cat /dev/random > ~/randomFile
```

Would it be written until the drive runs out of space, or would the system see a problem with this and stop it (like with an infinite symlink loop)?

Comment: I just wanted to add that concatenating random into devices was worth a few hours of fun in my youth. The framebuffer and sound card resulted in noise and the disk drive required me to do a low level reformat... good times.

Comment: OT: 'executable /dev/dsp? sounds like fun'

Comment: @BobRoberts I has similar adventures, with similar outcomes. I also used to ssh into colleagues' linux workstations and cat DTMF tones to the internal speaker, then play a busy tone, so it sounded like their PC was trying to FAX something out.  Ah, good times.

Comment: @TimKennedy how do you do that? Is there a /dev/ice for the 30mm audio jack?

Comment: @tkbx well, i'm dating myself, but back in the day you could cat a file to /dev/audio, and if it was a sound file (.wav) it would get played.

Comment: If you are putting dangerous commands up, I would recommend preceding it with an octothorpe as an additional safeguard.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It writes until the disk is full (usually there is still some space reserved for the root user). But as the pool of random data is limited, this could take a while.

If you need a certain amount of random data, use `dd`.
For 1MB:

```
dd if=/dev/random iflag=fullblock of=$HOME/randomFile bs=1M count=1
```

Other possibilities are mentioned in [answers to a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33629/how-can-i-populate-a-file-with-random-data).

**However, [in almost all cases](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939)** it is better to use `/dev/urandom` instead.
It does not block if the kernel thinks that it get out of entropy.
For better understanding, you can also read [myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Installing [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) speeds up `/dev/random` and also provides more entropy to `/dev/urandom`.

**EDIT**: `dd` needs the `fullblock` option as /dev/random (in opposite of `/dev/urandom`) can return incomplete blocks if the entropy pool is empty.

If your `dd` does not support units, write them out:

```
dd if=/dev/random iflag=fullblock of=$HOME/randomFile bs=1048576 count=1
```

Comment: 100 MiB of high-quality random data is a bit much... you should get a few bytes to seed some high-quality pseudo random number generator, like the Mersenne twister. If the application is critical (in a cryptographic sense) you _must_ go and read up on the matter, and perhaps hire an expert.

Comment: @vonbrand No, reading 100MB from `/dev/urandom` is fine, there's no reason not to do it. And do not use a Mersenne twister to do crypto. And [don't use `/dev/random` on Linux](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).

Comment: @jofel: No, the output of `/dev/urandom` _is_ fine for cryptographic use. Do not use `/dev/random`.

Comment: @Gilles, maybe I'm loosing it... I agree with everything you say, ans can't see where I said anything different.

Comment: @Gilles & vonbrand: Thanks for you comments, I improved my answer (now only 1MB in the example, /dev/urandom recommended).

Comment: @jofel `dd: bs: illegal numeric value`, 1000000 works

Comment: @tkbx With dd from e.g. GNU coreutils, you can use units like "M". I found, that `iflag=fullblock` is needed. Answer is updated.

Comment: I tend to write `head -c 123 /dev/urandom` to read a given amount of data from a device. I'd expect this to be less affected by the incomplete block scenario. Might be less performant, though.